# How to start writing a mobile phone app

Tags: android, vba, mobile

Am about to write my first mobile phone app and need to know how to start. It will need to access the phone's calendar to add tasks, and then automatically send a reminder e-mail to the user on the appropriate date. Some code will be needed to calculate forward dates. Any help greatfully received.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and emotions. But before jumping to stack overflow you need to study following

1. [Android developer training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)
2. [Calendar content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)
3. [Java Date Time Library to do date operations](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
4. [Post data to remote data base using retorfit](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845)

Comment: Hi Hardik     Thanks for taking the time and trouble to answer my question.  You are absolutely right about not trying too soon. I just didn't have any idea where to start - and a lot of my students use this site when they encounter problems.  Will have a look at all the above before I do anything else!  Will be back at a later date.  Thanks again Dave